# How to use countVectorizer to test new data after doing some training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, vectorization

I was using countVectorizer like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=200, min_df=2, max_df=0.7, 
stop_words=stopwords.words('arabic'))  
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Now this code will convert string to binary, and then I'm going to train the data.
However, I now have some test data that are small. How can I covert it to binary form so I can actually compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `vectorizer` that you fit on your training data to transform your text into the same format expected by your trained model:

```
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_text_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Array mapping from feature integer indices to feature name:

```py
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```